# erro na execução do node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

ola, estou com esse erro no meu app:

> Servidor Rodando!
>   URL: /
>   Method: GET
>   _http_outgoing.js:482
>       throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
>       ^
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
>       at Server.http.createServer (C:\Users\Samuel Melo da Silva\Desktop\node.js\index.js:13:8)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:193:13)
>       at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:680:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:113:17)

codigo:

```
const http = require('http');

let server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{

    console.log('URL:', req.url);
    console.log('Method:', req.method);

    res.end('ok');

    switch(req.url){
        case '/':
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.end('<h1>Olá</h1>');
            break;
        case '/users':
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify({
                user:[{
                    name:'Samuel',
                    email: 'samuel@samuel.com',
                    id: 1
                }]
            }));
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(300, '127.0.0.1', ()=>{

    console.log('Servidor Rodando!');

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está dizendo que você não pode alterar os `headers` da resposta depois de já ter enviado a mesma.

Note que você está utilizando o comando `res.end('ok')` e logo depois no seu `switch` você faz `res.statusCode = 200` e `res.setHeader()`. Isso não é possível.